# List items not updating outside of for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime, series

I have a pandas series of dates in string format, but some of the values are a non-date string. 
I tried updating them individually to circumvent the non-date strings, but even though the values appear to be changed inside the for loop, the list remains unchanged once printed out of the loop.

```
diedlist = df['Died'].tolist()
for item in diedlist:
    if item == '(living)':
        continue
    print(item)
    item = dt.datetime.strptime(item, ("%b %d, %Y"))
    print(item)
```

The initial `print(item)` prints out the date in the existing format MMM DD, YYYY. 
The `print(item)` after the `strptime()` function prints out the date in the new date format `("%b %d, %Y")` , and returns a datetime object of `YYYY-MM-DD` as expected. 
However, upon printing the list **outside** the loop, the items appear in their old format once again, as if untouched.

thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the item back in the list:

```
for index, item in enumerate(diedlist):
    if item == '(living)':
        continue
    item = dt.datetime.strptime(item, ("%b %d, %Y"))
    diedlist[index] = item
```